# ASP Chart Control - Chart Title CSS Class name

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, charts

I've searched the web and looked through the `Chart Control for .Net Framework` example project but couldnt locate anything related to add a `cssClass` to the `Title` object of the chart,
any suggestion how to achieve this?
I want to be able to change the color of the `Chart's Title` from the `css`

```
<aspChart:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="153px" Height="170" EnableViewState="true">
      <BorderSkin SkinStyle="Emboss" />
        <Titles>
             <aspChart:Title ShadowColor="32, 0, 0, 0">
             </aspChart:Title>
        </Titles>
```

Comment: Can you post the rendered html?

Comment: asp.net renders the chart as an image, I can't detect the rendered `Title` unfortunately

Comment: If the title is just in an image, I don't see how CSS would be of any use to your problem of changing the title color?

Comment: True, thats what I discovered after checking the rendered html :)

Comment: Ok, glad you've got a solution at least! Added Answer in case it helps someone else.

Comment: I didnt get a solution!, i just got another obstacle

Answer (score 0):

The title in the aspChart control is in the generated image, so it can't be changed by CSS.

If you want a CSS controllable title, add the title with HTML and remove the control title.

If you want to set the title color of the control, you can do it server side when you create the Title with the following constructor:

```
Title(string text, System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Docking docking, System.Drawing.Font font, System.Drawing.Color color)
```